# How can I cast an object to string and use it in a Linq query using Reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, reflection, expression-trees

There's the problem I made an Extension method to IQueryable and I want to get property name and value to do a select on it the thing is that I am using Expression tree and try to search rows by the use of Contain() method which is needs a parameter of type string to do the job. my code is doing well while I do the search over string properties but I want this method to do the search on other types like int, decimal, datetime and even booleans so I need to get the property cast it to string and search for the matching values.

what I tried so far is:

```
        private static readonly MethodInfo _tostring = typeof(Object).GetMethod("ToString") ?? throw new Exception("Cannot create Method");

        public static IQueryable<T> Search<T>(this IQueryable<T> items, string propertyName, string filterValue)
        {
            MethodInfo _compare =
                (((Expression<Func<string, bool>>)(s => s.Contains("aa"))).Body as MethodCallExpression ?? throw new Exception("Cannot Create Method"))
                .Method;
            var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName) ?? throw new Exception("Couldn't Get the property");
            var row = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "row");

            
            Expression prop = Expression.Property(row, property);
            // now making sure if the type is string
            if (property.PropertyType != typeof(string))
            {
                //Here I want to cast it to string but the problem is exactly here anything I try feels like a dead end
                prop = Expression.Call(prop, _tostring);
            }

            var func =
                Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
                (
                    Expression.Call
                    (
                        prop,
                        _compare,
                        Expression.Constant(filterValue)
                    ),
                    row
                );

            return items.Where(func);
        }
```

Comment: Add details which ORM do you use, version and sample of usage. I have answered a tons of such questions and it is easy to correct of your Expression Tree.

Comment: Your problem is you are attempting to call `Object.ToString` instead of the correct `{PropertyType}.ToString` that matches the property's type. You need to find the `ToString` to call dynamically based on the type of the property e.g. `var _tostring = property.PropertyType.GetMethod("ToString")`.

Comment: I'm using EF core 7  by the way I got help from some other guy. lack of experience in Expression trees. I updated the code with the correct solution.

Comment: @NetMage There's nothing wrong with that call. I should have used polymorphism there was a small mistake now it's completely functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and tested it with some dummy objects; it seems to work.

I refined my answer to use `ToString`

```
var prop = Expression.Property(row, property);

Expression expression = prop;

if (prop.Type != typeof(string))
{
   expression = Expression.Call(prop, "ToString", Type.EmptyTypes);
}

var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
(
     Expression.Call
     (
       expression,
       _compare,
       Expression.Constant(filterValue)
     ),
     row
);
```

The above expression tree will be compiled to,

If the property type is not a string,

`.Where(s => s.property.ToString().Contains("filter")))`

If it's a string type,

`.Where(s => s.property.Contains("filter")))`

Comment: Unfortunately it's not working it throws runtime exception rather than compile time exception.The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Product>()\r\n      .Where(f => ((object)f.Name).ToString().Contains(\"Pro\"))' could not be translated. Additional information: Translation of method 'object.ToString' failed.

Comment: I see, you are using this for EF queries. This only works for POCO. I will take another look. The error says the LINQ cannot be translated to SQL query.

Comment: I did some search, and it turns out that if you want to use LINQ to SQL, EF does not support `toString()` see https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6264

Comment: @CharlesHan Actually that issue says it was fixed in EF Core 2

Comment: Did you try EF Core 7? you are right that it seems to support ToString() https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions

Comment: @AshkanKhalaj i have updated my answer and see if that works for you now.